# How can I "unlink" storyboards between two XCode projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I have two XCode projects - they are two different versions of the same app. I started out with one version of the app, then for historical reasons had to make a copy of it with slightly different content and implementation.

When I made the copy, I copied over all the story projects from project A into project B. Everything was working fine. However, I'm noticing that the storyboards in project B are actually just pointing to project A!

Meaning, if I go into storyboard "Foo" in project B and make some changes, they show up in project A as well! This is obviously not what I want, I want the codebases to know nothing about each other and to be completely separate.

So is there a way I can tell project B to just have all its own stuff and never look at project A again? Also, how do I prevent this from happening in the future? XCode does some weird stuff without telling you, it seems.

Comment: It's not typical for Xcode. I recommend to look into project files structure in Finder, make sure that you have two separated files for storyboards, and then re-add different storyboards for both projects (right click on project structure in Xcode -> Add Files to "Project"...

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out -- in my `project.pbxproj` file there was a `path =` reference to my other project. I have no idea how that happened. I removed that reference and copied all the storyboard files over by hand. It appears to be okay now.